# integring yolov5 in java for android APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, model, yolov5

please I need an example of model 'last.pt' generated by yolov5, and implemented in Java to dectect objects.
I want to apply it on my own model for building an android APK.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need is mobile optimized versions of PyTorch or Tensorflow that enables mobile inference, PyTorch Mobile and TensorflowLite, respectively. [This repository](https://github.com/zldrobit/yolov5) does just that. It runs TFLite and uses yolov5 model. The fact that yolov5 is the first in the family to be originally implemented in PyTorch makes this possible.

In the models folder you will find a script that converts your .pt model to .tflite which TFLite needs as weight format. You will find more details on how you can do that conversion. The application has single page and performs real-time inference but of course you can modify it however you want.

There are plenty of questions in this [pull request](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/pull/1127) and the author is actively responding if you have further questions.